# AC step down circuit

Tags: transformer, ac, safety

I have a quick question about a circuit I want to build, namely a low voltage AC power source.

I attached a picture of the schematic.

Are there any safety concerns that I might have to pay attention to that are not addressed in the schematic? It is a pretty simple circuit, but it is my first time working with AC, so I wanted to be safe.

[image: schematic of the circuit]

Comment: You would be better off buying a UL listed, commercial off-the-shelf transformer assembly, which simply provides split phase low voltage AC output. That removes essentially all the hazard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The primary side (230VAC) needs a fuse.  I think the [datasheet for the VTX-146-015-106](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/3167540.pdf) says there's a fusible link in the primary side to protect against overheating, but I'd still put a fuse in.
2. Those TVS diodes will make a mess of your AC.  You do not need them.
3. You seem to want a switchable 6VAC/12VAC output.  Use the following schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fM6DDg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice!